# User action tracking in REST

Tags: rest

When designing action tracking api in REST what should be the Http method to track, should we use POST(since its submitting the data to server on what is user action) or should we use GET (like used in image beacon techniques)

Comment: Could you please tell more about your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should choose easiest to use method for tracking.

For me is GET.

REST standart is only list of recomendations not neccessary to carry them all.

And if you choose POST, you couldn't use it as image beacon.

Comment: But can get http method be used to post data?

Comment: What data you want to send?

Comment: The data sent are like the action he has taken and data about on which  object he has taken action on.

Comment: GET /track/:userId?action=foo&object=bar